# UIToolbar in Swift not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I'm trying to add a UIToolbar to a UIViewController, and it's not working. Anybody know what's wrong?

```
var toolBar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    title = "Title"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    webView = WKWebView()
    view = self.webView!

    // Toolbar
    toolBar.frame = self.view.bounds
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    toolBar.setItems(toolbarItems, animated: true)
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    view.addSubview(toolBar)
}
```

It would be much appreciated. I've tried looking at other Stack overflow posts but I couldn't find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure without being able to see your project but here are my thoughts:

- I think you are wrong and toolbar is there but you just don't see it as far as your navigation bar is translucent and covers top part of your view. So, you can just change it to opaque mode or adjust toolbar position.
- But there is another thing. What the point of adding toolbar view in case using navigation bar? Just use standard one with all customization you need.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to see toolbars in the event of when-view-will-appear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  ...
  if let nav = self.navigationController {
     nav.isToolbarHidden = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var toolBar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRectMake(0, 524, 320, 44))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
       self.view.addSubview(toolBar)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, the problem was that I was supposed to be using the Toolbar in the Navigation Controller, not programmatically. Thanks everyone for your answers!